# How do i pass two th:object in a single form

Tags: java, html, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf and couldn't found a way to pass two th:objects in a single HTML form. how can I pass two different entity objects.in this case, my entities are Patient and Doctor. My form is given below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>LOG IN PAGE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form th:action="@{/loggedProfile}" th:object="${patient,doctor}"
            method="get">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="patientEmail">Email address</label> <input type="email"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your email"
                    th:field="*{eMail}"> <small id="emailHelp"
                    class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email
                    with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="patientPassword">Password</label> <input type="password"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Password"
                    th:field="*{password}">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<div th:insert="Header-Footer/common_header_footer"></div>
</html>
```

Here is my controller, its raw.

```
    @GetMapping("/logIn")
public String logIn(Model model) {
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    model.addAttribute("patient", patient);
    
    Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
    model.addAttribute("doctor", doctor);
    
    return "UI-Pages/LogIn_Page";
}

@GetMapping("/loggedProfile")
public String loggedProfile(@ModelAttribute Doctor doctor,@ModelAttribute Patient patient,Model model) {
    doctor = docRep.findByeMailAndPassword(doctor.geteMail(), doctor.getPassword());
    patient = patRep.findByeMailAndPassword(patient.geteMail(), patient.getPassword());
    model.addAttribute("doctor", doctor);
    model.addAttribute("patient", patient);
    return "Profile-Pages/Patient_Profile";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new object that contains a `Patient` and a `Doctor`.

```
public class LoginForm {
  private Patient patient;
  private Doctor doctor;
  
  // getters and setters
}
```

Then access the fields like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/loggedProfile}" th:object="${form}"
  th:field="*{patient.eMail}"

  ....
  th:field="*{doctor.password}"
</form>
```

Etc...

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to use a dedicated Data Transfer Object that maps to the fields in the form data:

```
public class LoginFormData {
  private String email;
  private String password;
}
```

Then transform from the `Patient` or `Doctor` entity into `LoginFormData` and back in your controller.

Side note:

- Use `th:method="post"` in the form with a `@PostMapping` in the controller if it is the intention to use the form to change data
- Having a method `findByeMailAndPassword` is not something that you should have. Passwords should be in the database in plain text, and it would be strange to try to find a certain user with its plain text password.

Comment: Thank you, I've got an alternate idea from your answer